# numbering an output in order

Tags: php, mysql

i have made a image slider(or what ever you want to call it) and it displays the 6 latest images. Under the current bigger image you have all 6 of the most recent images , and the process works all fine but when you click the smaller image, it doesn't bring up the big image straight away. Because the very latest image is first its 'active' and has its own `<a href="#1>`  and  so the `href="#1"` is entered as i can manipulate the a tag as it is there. But as i used a foreach to bring up the next 5 images from 2nd to 6th in descending order from date submitted, i cant give each individual result there own `href"#number"` so they can link up with the bigger images, is there a way to assign each result a number by taking what position it sits within the query then adding 1or2 to the answer which would then give the corresponding number in the href so when clicked, the larger image which is linked to the href number too, it will make the larger image appear straight away.

the code from the tutorial that i have amended looks like this ..

```
<?php
$latest_headlines = get_latest_headlines(); 
foreach ($latest_headlines as $latest_headline) {
?>
<a href="#1" class="cross-link active-thumb"><img src="img/<?php echo $latest_headline['img_title'].'.'.$latest_headline['img_ext']; ?>" class="nav-thumb" alt="<?php echo $latest_headline['title']; ?>" /></a>

<?php   
}
?>
<div id="movers-row">
<?php 
$recent_headlines = get_recent_headlines();
foreach ($recent_headlines as $recent_headline) {
?>
        <div><a href="#<?php echo $row_num; ?>" class="cross-link"><img src="img/<?php echo $recent_headline['img_title'].'.'.$recent_headline['img_ext']; ?>" class="nav-thumb" alt="<?php echo $recent_headline['title']; ?>" /></a></div>
<?php
} 
?>
</div>
```

And here are my two functions to get the results, and before people start picking at all the problems ive done, just want to say this is the way ive learnt it im new, it maybe all wrong but its what stuck in my head to do things this way and its worked(ish) so far....

```
function get_recent_headlines() {
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM `story`
        ORDER BY `submit_date` DESC
        LIMIT 1, 5 ";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$recent_headlines = array();

while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false) {
    $recent_headlines[] = array(
'title'       => $row['title'],
'img_title'   => $row['img_title'],
'img_ext'     => $row['image_ext']  
            );  
}
return $recent_headlines;
}

function get_latest_headlines() {
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM `story`
        ORDER BY `submit_date` DESC
        LIMIT 1 ";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$lastest_headlines = array();

while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false) {
    $latest_headlines[] = array(
'title'       => $row['title'],
'img_title'   => $row['img_title'],
'img_ext'     => $row['image_ext']  
            );      
}
return $latest_headlines;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your query of your function get_recent_headlines()

it uses a variable, and increment it in the SELECT statement:

```
    `$sql = "SELECT *,(@row:=@row+1) AS rowno
    FROM `story` inner join (SELECT @row:=0) AS row_count
    ORDER BY `submit_date` DESC
    LIMIT 1, 5 ";`
```

Comment: sorry about this but then how would i go about getting the numbers, like to echo them out? would it just be like the rest but echo $recent_headline['rowno/row_count']; im just not sure sorry

Comment: that seems to work near perfectly thank you so much! the one problem is that the `(@row:=@row+1)` ads 1 as it should but the numbers start at 0 so pic pic2 is num1, pic3 is num2, pic4 is num3 and so on, so i just changed the `(SELECT @row:=0)` to `(SELECT @row:=1)` which then started the counting at the appropriate place!, thanks so much for that! i hopefully understand whats happening so i know for the future!! cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use a user variable to get a sequence number within MySQL.:-

```
SELECT Sub1.*,@aCount:=@aCount+1 AS aSequence
FROM (SELECT *
        FROM `story`

        ORDER BY `submit_date` DESC) Sub1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @aCount := 0) Sub2
LIMIT 1, 5
```